# Is there an easy way to change to previously active branch?

Tags: git, branch, msysgit

I'm using git (in fact, msysgit) 1.6.4 on Windows. Most of the time I'm doing work in some feature branches. Every now and then, I want to hop back to master to cherry-pick one particular commit I did in my feature branch - usually because it's a useful bugfix which makes sense even without the feature. My workflow is like this - if this is unnecessarily complicated, please tell me :-) :

```
git checkout -b mycoolfeaturebranch
// hack away, implementing a feature and one bugfix (while I'm at it)

git add file_with_bugfix.cpp
git commit -m "Fixed bug 12345  // commit the bugfix
git checkout master             // hop over to master
git cherry-pick                 // bring the bugfix into master
```

At this point, I usually want to hop back to my feature branch to continue work on the feature. Unfortunately, my branch names tend to become a little long (like, 'mycoolfeaturebranch') and I don't have git branch name tab completion on Windows.

Is there maybe something like `cd -` on Unix shells (which hops to the previous directory, useful for toggling between two directories)? A `git checkout -` would be great. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $GIT/Documentation/RelNotes-1.6.2.txt:

- "git checkout -" is a shorthand for "git checkout @{-1}".

Did you try it?

Comment: Argh! I tried it with some older git version, but didn't retry it since I upgraded to git 1.6.4. D'oh! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 git checkout @{-1}
```

From [git rev-parse](http://www.eu.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html):

> The special construct `@{-<n>}` means the th branch checked out before the current one.

---

As mentioned by [Stefan Näwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181986/stefan-nawe) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599934/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-to-previously-active-branch/1600067#1600067):

> "`git checkout -`" is a shorthand for "`git checkout @{-1}`".

Even though the syntax `@{-1}` has been around 1.6.2, it is only since 1.6.2 it is fully effective, as Junio C. Hamano comments [back in  February 2009](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg682231.html) (emphasis mine):

> The @{-1} syntax was added long before you started getting hyperactive
>   this round, but it will be in 1.6.2 and **has been advertised as "usable
>   anywhere you can use a branch name", but in reality it is not**.
>
> I have been fixing up various places to match the reality with the claim.
>   I am making "`git merge @{-1}`" work now.

---

(Note: that differs from `@{<n>}`

> A ref followed by the suffix @ with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{1}`, `{15}`) to specify the n-th prior value of that ref.
>   For example `master@{1}`  is the immediate prior value of master while `master@{5}` is the 5th prior value of master.
>   This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log ($GIT_DIR/logs/).
>
> You can use the `@` construct with an empty ref part to get at a reflog of the current branch.
>   For example, if you are on the branch `blabla`, then `@{1}` means the same as `blabla@{1}`.

)

Comment: Excellent! Works well - unfortunately @{-1} is a little annoying to type. For now, I created an alias called 'git cc' which does a 'git checkout @{-1}'. Or is there maybe a way to make 'git checkout -' an alias for 'git checkout @{-1}'?

Comment: `git checkout -` functions as `git checkout @{-1}`. The `@{-1}` is special case of the more generic `@{-n}`, i.e. nth last checked out branch.